# What do I put for <TargetID> in android development

Tags: android, linux

Im trying to create android project with Command Line Tools and this is what I have done thus far.

Change directories into the Android SDK’s tools/ path.

Execute:

```
android list targets
```

Following output:

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
 Name: Android 4.4.2
 Type: Platform
 API level: 19
 Revision: 3
 Skins: WXGA800-7in, HVGA, WSVGA, QVGA, WQVGA432, WXGA720, WXGA800, WQVGA400, WVGA800       (default), WVGA854
 Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a, default/x86
 ----------
 id: 2 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs x86:19"
 Name: Google APIs x86
 Type: Add-On
 Vendor: Google Inc.
 Revision: 4
 Description: Android + Google APIs x86
 Based on Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
 Libraries:
  * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
      Collection of video effects
  * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
      API for USB Accessories
  * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
      API for Google Maps
 Skins: WSVGA, WXGA720, WVGA800 (default), HVGA, WVGA854, WQVGA400, QVGA, WXGA800,   WQVGA432, WXGA800-7in
 Tag/ABIs : default/x86
 ----------
id: 3 or "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"
 Name: Google APIs
 Type: Add-On
 Vendor: Google Inc.
 Revision: 4
 Description: Android + Google APIs
 Based on Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)
 Libraries:
  * com.google.android.media.effects (effects.jar)
      Collection of video effects
  * com.android.future.usb.accessory (usb.jar)
      API for USB Accessories
  * com.google.android.maps (maps.jar)
      API for Google Maps
 Skins: WSVGA, WXGA720, WVGA800 (default), HVGA, WVGA854, WQVGA400, QVGA, WXGA800, WQVGA432, WXGA800-7in
```

Tag/ABIs : default/armeabi-v7a

Execute:

```
android create project --target <target-id> --name MyFirstApp \
--path <path-to-workspace>/MyFirstApp --activity MainActivity \
--package com.example.myfirstapp
```

input:

```
android create project --target <3> --name MyFirstApp --path <path-to-workspace>/MyFirstApp --    activity MainActivity --package com.example.myfirstapp
```

response:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `3'
```

What do I put for the target ID ? I've tried the number and what is in the " "

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link : http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html. I think you need to remove the "< >" from the target number.

Comment: Thanks, now when I input this  sudo ./android create project -t 1 -n MyFirstApp \ --path </home/alcamech/project>/MyFirstApp -activity MainActivity \ --package com.example.myfirstapp , it responds with the following 
bash: /MyFirstApp: Permission denied

Comment: I think you may need to change permissions for the project folder. in the shell, use the command `chmod -R 755 /Path to ProjectFolder`. This will change the folder (and all the files inside) permissions to Read, write execute for user and read,write for Group/other.

Comment: Still permission denied

Comment: hmm. Did it say permission denied for the chmod command or for the android command. Also can you navigate to the folder and run ls -l and see what the permissions are for the directory?

Comment: android command once I tried it again, and the ls -l command returns: total 0

Comment: 0? May you type in the command for the ls that you used.  You have to run it in you project folder, not the MyFirstApp folder.

Comment: I did ls -l within the project folder

Comment: Total 0 is indicating that it has 0 files/directories in that folder.